# Speed up calculation in np.array

Tags: python, numpy, similarity

Following setup:
Normkurven are values for each day of the year for different classes. Here I got a Variable called Norm that is a pandas.DataFrame() with 13 classes as columns and 365 rows

NDVI is an array of  (in total 102x3600x3600) in this case to speed things up the shape is (102x300x300), whereas 102 is for 102 days where I got data. 300x300 is basically a square in der middle of my area of interest. I flattened the array to decrease the need of indexing.

My goal is to calculate the similarities for each pixel to each class and store the class with the highest similarity in a list.

```
import numpy as np
from operator import itemgetter
import similaritymeasures as sim
from time import time

Classification = []   


t0 = time()
for i in range(NDVI.shape[1]):
    TS = np.zeros((len(DOY),2))
    TS[:,0] = np.arange(1,len(DOY)+1,1)
    TS[:,1] = NDVI[:,i]
    TS = TS[~np.isnan(TS[:,1])]
    results = []

    if TS.size == 0:
        Classification[0,i] = "No data"
    else:
        for j in Norm:
            Norm_arr = np.zeros((365,2))
            Norm_arr[:,0] = np.arange(1,366,1)
            Norm_arr[:,1] = Norm[j].to_numpy()
            diff = sim.frechet_dist(TS,Norm_arr)
            results.append((j, diff))
        results.sort(key = itemgetter(1))
        Classification.append() = results[0][0]
    print(i)
print((time()-t0)/60)
```

As you can see I am iterating through every cell and each class and calculate the similarities. I want to test different methods of the similaritymeasures and compare the results.
The first method was sim.pcm() which was calculated within 3 hours, but over night the frechet_distance took like 8 hours for 2000 cells, which is far to long.

Is it possible to restructure my code to get it doing what it is but way faster?

Comment: have you tried using this package? http://numba.pydata.org/

Comment: mrk I decided to write a "new" function for my Sim-calculation with the following Code: @jit def Sim(T,N): diff = sim.frechet_dist(T,N) return diff where T and N are TS and Norm and m is the used method. Got a warning "<ipython-input-29-4ba3a4e1fa29>:1: NumbaWarning: 
Compilation is falling back to object mode WITH looplifting enabled because Function "Sim" failed type inference due to: Unknown attribute 'frechet_dist' of type Module(<module 'similaritymeasures' from 'C:\\Users\\Felix\\anaconda3\\envs\\Py\\lib\\site-packages\\similaritymeasures\\__init__.py'>)"